# Solr match string starting with

Tags: solr

I have imported data from my database into Solr for querying purpose.

A sample of data is as below...

```
NAMATJIRA,DRIVE,,WARAMANGA,ACT
DOUGLAS WATERHOUSE,DRIVE,,DUNLOP,ACT
WARDELL,DRIVE,,BARDEN RIDGE,NSW
```

In solr admin page, when I run the query

```
street_name:wa* AND street_name:drive*
```

I get all the records as above. Is there a way to filter so that I get only the ones starting with WA?

UPDATE : Added schema  information

```
<field name="street_name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>    
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: show us your solr schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the type you are using it to analyze that field is tokenizing that into several terms, so

```
NAMATJIRA,DRIVE,,WARAMANGA,ACT
```

becomes (a field containing multiple terms, then it's probably also lowercasing etc)

```
NAMATJIRA 
DRIVE
WARAMANGA
ACT
```

That is why your query matches it, because one of the values starts with 'wa'.

To fix this, just change the type of your field to use KeywordTokenizerFactory, that keeps everything as a single term.

Comment: Changed to KeywordTokenizerFactory (schema information updated, see original question), however, the results haven't changed.

Comment: did you reindex? you need to